# UIScrollView: recreating content view in scrollViewDidEndZooming

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I would like to ask, is it correct to recreate content view in `scrollViewDidEndZooming` method? Is there any potential problems with this? I use the following code:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale {
   [self.contentView removeFromSuperview];

   self.contentView = [[ContentView alloc] init ...];
   ...

   [scrollView addSubview:self.contentView];
}
```

and with the simulator everything works correctly, but when I run this example on device sometimes when I zoom with pinch gesture I have a `scale` value set to 1.0 that is very strange because actually it should be set to zoom scale that differ from 1.0. Also, could somebody advice should I add `self.contentView = nil` after `removeFromSubview` call?

NOTE: I use SDK 3.1.2

Thank you in advance

Comment: May I ask what are you trying to achieve exactly? There could be another "more healthy" options

Comment: In general I want to achieve ability to work with large content views in UIScrollView with full functionality to zoom and sliding and also sharped content on it. I tried many ways to do it from CATiledLayer to offscreen bitmap context but still didn't find an appropriate solution. Currently I've got some solution that can be accepted and with the simulator everything works correctly, but on device I have a problems.

Comment: It seems for me that scrollViewDidEndZooming works something like asynchronously, because actually below in code I setZoomScale to 1.0 but before I also disable the Max and Min zoom levels. Sometimes also when I set the self.contentView to nil after removeFromSubView I have view argument also set to nil exact after the method call (in first output of NSLog, just before actual statement self.contentView = nil and removeFromSuperview)